# Methods of filtering noise caused by DC brush motors

Tags: motor, robotics, dc, filter, dc-motor

I am looking for any information that would help me reduce the power rail noise and EMI of DC brush motors. I am building a robot that is powered by 2 x 250 W 24V DC motors.

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/capacitors-and-motors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The noise could be generated by either the brushes (commutation) or the driver if its PWM.  Easiest fix for brush noise (which would be random or 'static') is a capacitor right across the PMDC motor leads, something like a 1 µF, 100 V ceramic capacitor might be a good starting point.

If the PWM supply is causing problems (something with narrow spectral content), you would need a choke between the PWM power rail and your main supply.

Comment: If it is a PWM, you may also need to shield the wiring between the motor and controller to prevent EMI.

Answer (score 5):

The capacitor that Nick T mentions is the most important -- directly across the 2 motor leads, mounted directly on the motor.

Occasionally that is not enough.

Some people get further improvements by adding one capacitor per motor lead between that motor lead and the metal case of the motor.

A few people go even further, adding ferrite bead "choke" and another capacitor to form a ["pi filter"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/pi_filter) -- see
["Nophead's inteference suppressor"](http://reprap.org/wiki/Nophead%27s_Extruder_Tweaks#Interference_suppressor)
and the pages it links to
for the ugly "before" o'scope traces and the pretty "after" o'scope photos.